# How to expand query APIs in BigchainDB 2.0?

Tags: python, blockchain, bigchaindb

By default BigchainDB provides some [API](http://docs.bigchaindb.com/projects/server/en/latest/http-client-server-api.html#bigchaindb-root-url) for us.

```
"api": {
    "v1": {
      "assets": "/api/v1/assets/",
      "blocks": "/api/v1/blocks/",
      "docs": "https://docs.bigchaindb.com/projects/server/en/v2.0.0/http-client-server-api.html",
      "metadata": "/api/v1/metadata/",
      "outputs": "/api/v1/outputs/",
      "streams": "ws://localhost:9985/api/v1/streams/valid_transactions",
      "transactions": "/api/v1/transactions/",
      "validators": "/api/v1/validators"
    }
}
```

And in [white paper for BigchainDB](https://www.bigchaindb.com/whitepaper/bigchaindb-whitepaper.pdf) **page 4** we can read, that we can create our own API for it

> By default, BigchainDB 2.0 creates some MongoDB indexes and the
>   BigchainDB HTTP API includes some endpoints for doing basic queries.
>   However, as outlined in the previous paragraph, each node operator can
>   add additional indexes and query APIs.

I found out [routes.py](https://github.com/bigchaindb/bigchaindb/blob/master/bigchaindb/web/routes.py) (where API urls are set) and [query.py](https://github.com/bigchaindb/bigchaindb/blob/master/bigchaindb/backend/localmongodb/query.py) (where methods to get data from mongo are defined) in [files' source](https://github.com/bigchaindb/bigchaindb), but there is no merge opportunity to expand query api without forking repository.

Is there any variant to add own API without changing original code?